# Mouse hovering event

Tags: vb.net

I want to do an mouse hovering event, when the mouse is over an button I want to change button text color and font size, I have try this code but doesn't  work:

```
 Private Sub Command1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
Command1.ForeColor.MediumBlue()
    Command1.FontSize = 10
End Sub

Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
Command1.ForeColor.White()
    Command1.FontSize = 8
End Sub
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion i have search on Google and try different ways with mouse event handler but didn't work.

Comment: Please add tag `winforms` or `wpf`, according to forms technology you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, instead of tracking every mouse move, you can rely on **MouseEnter** and **MouseLeave** events of the button.

Second, do not forget to add `Handles <Control>.<Event>` clause at the declaration of your event-handling procedures.

Result:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Command1.MouseEnter
    Command1.FontSize = 10
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Command1.MouseLeave
    Command1.FontSize = 8
End Sub
```

Also please do not forget that some users are preferring keyboard control.
This means that

1. You might want to equip the button with an accelerator.

   `Command1.Text = "&Launch"`   (now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> activates the button)

   Note: accelerator character for [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) is `&`, for [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) is `_`.
2. You might want to make your entry/leave effect also when the button receives/looses keyboard focus (focus is moved using <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key).

Answer (score 2):

You can try making your changes into MouseEnter and MouseLeave

```
    Private Sub RightButton_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RightButton.MouseEnter
        RightButton.ForeColor = Color.AliceBlue
        RightButton.Font = New Font(RightButton.Font, 12)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RightButton_MouseLeave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RightButton.MouseLeave
        RightButton.ForeColor = Color.White
        RightButton.Font = New Font(RightButton.Font, 10)
    End Sub
```