# Change font when mouse is over a certain text, and revert back. (Event Handler)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, event-handling

I have an assignment were the requirements are to create a grid of textboxes (no I cant use datagridview or import libraries).

Now since text boxes are a bit rudimentary, an Idea popped into my head to do like excel (highlighting cells). now I wish to highlight what is written inside a textbox when:

-I click on it,
-when mouse hovers on it
-reverts back when another text box is selected and or mouse is away from the cell.

For eg:

when clicked and writing in the cell its red,

when another cell is clicked but mouse is hovering on another cell, the text on which the mouse is hovering becomes blue,

when I click on another cell and mouse is not hovering over the cell it returns to being black.

I wish to used event handlers.

I know the method syntax and what not, but what do you call the thingy (ie. .textchange to change text .validate to validate what is written, .click to show what is clicked. etc)

also if anyone can provide a link of the list of all event handlers which can be utilised will be of immense help.

I wanna pawn this assignment.

already have 3 event handlers for other things, currently using

textchanged,
validate,
click.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: winforms, sryy fairly new at stack overflow.

Comment: Select your `TextBox` control on the form in design mode, press F4 key, in the properties window click on lightening icon in properties window and you will see a list of events for your text box.

Comment: `Enter` and `Leave` are events which you may want to try.

Comment: the textboxes are not created from toolbox, they are hardcoded into a grid of 26x26 textboxes created by a nested for loop. They also have inherited properties.

Comment: Well, you can wire up those events in code. Pretty common. When you create a new TextBox object also add the event; you can use a lambda: `[NewTextBox].Leave += (obj, evt) => { [NewTextBox].Font = new Font(...); };`. Or a standard handler: `[NewTextBox].Leave += this.TextBoxCommonLeaveEvent; private void TextBoxCommonLeaveEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) { (sender as TextBox).Font = new Font(...)}`. Of course you can set pre-built Fonts instead of creating a new one each time. Dispose of it these a Form closes.

Comment: Another unsolicited advice: unless aren't already, use a TableLayoutPanel or a FlowLayoutPanel to organize your TextBox controls. Managing these two containers has its learning curve if you haven't used them before, but you'll be glad you did.

Comment: why can you not use a datagridview ?

Comment: GuidoG. Assignment specifications. I KNOW!. its the reason i cant find anything online to help me, cos everyone either uses datagrid view or imports libraries.

Comment: If you are using Systme.Windows.Forms.Textbox, there is a MouseHover Event you can use.  Also check out this post on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717199/mouse-hovering-event